# how can I extrude wall evenly?

Tags: extrude

[image]

wall, and floor thickness is different when I extrude faces along normals. How can I make it evenly??

Comment: Select your object in _Object mode_ and press Ctrl+A (apply) and select "Scale" before extruding. There are also additional options such as "Extrude Even" that appear in the _Operator Panel_ in the bottom-left of the viewport after extruding.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Oh my God!!!!!!!!! The key was the "Scale"!!!!!! Thank you So Much